# Javascript: Unable to pull from localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Making a todo list for a class project - able to get the item to "add" and append to the list, but when you refresh the page, the item returns as `undefined`.  Checking `localStorage.todo`, I see it pulling part of the values I need, but aren't in use yet, but not the actual `innerText`.  I started adding bits for a line-through to check off completed items and a remove button, but that was commented out and hopefully isn't impacting things - was trying to isolate the error.

I'm guessing my issue is something in the `localStorage.setItem`, but I'm not sure what it would be.  I've tried changing the `newTodo.innerText` value to other variables in use but nothing returns.  Below returns an input value I enter, but again, is lost when the page refreshes.

```
const todoForm = document.querySelector('#todoForm');
const todoList = document.querySelector('#todoList');
let todoItem = document.querySelector('#todoItem');

// Pull from storage
const savedList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || [];
for (let i = 0; i < savedList.length; i++)
{
let newTodo = document.createElement('li');
newTodo.innerText = savedList[i].task;
todoList.appendChild(newTodo);

}

// Add Item
todoForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let newTodo = document.createElement('li');
    let newItem = document.querySelector('#todoItem').value;
    newTodo.innerText = newItem;
    todoForm.reset();
    todoList.appendChild(newTodo);

// Clear Form Field on submit and storage  

    savedList.push({ task: newTodo.innertext, isCompleted: false });
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(savedList));

});
// Add Remove Button
    // let removeItem = document.createElement('button');
    // removeItem.innerText = "Remove";
    // newTodo.append(removeItem);

// Strike through item or remove item
// todoList.addEventListener('click', function(e){
//     if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON'){
//         e.target.parentElement.remove();
//     }
//     else if (e.target.tagName === 'LI'){
//         e.target.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
//     }  
 
// });
```

Comment: How are you loading the page? local webserver or just opening it directly from harddrive?

Comment: Dede below noticed my error.  I didn't notice innertext wasn't innerText.  It appears to be working.  To answer your question, it was local from the harddrive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

camelcase is wrong not `innertext` but `innerText`

```
savedList.push({ task: newTodo.innerText, isCompleted: false })
```

Comment: I've stared at this for 1-2 hours.  This hurts my head.  Thanks.